# Scrape a form that loads after connection

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape from a website that may scrape from other sites - TripAdvisor. 
But I think the information only loads after I connect to the site. For example: I want to get the names and prices of the best rates on this hotel...
http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60956-d288617-Reviews-Mokara_Hotel_and_Spa-San_Antonio_Texas.html

As of now its "otels" at $238 and if I search ('//span[@class="providerLogo"]'), it comes up blank.

Anyone encounter this?

Comment: What exact information are you trying to scrape? If the site loads data dynamically via Javascript, you might have success scraping the same data URL directly.

Comment: I want to scrape the name of the top provider so I can find the overall cheapest provider of the entire site.